# Dynamic Theme Change Based On System's Dark & Light Mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, flutter-theme

I have been working on dynamic dark and light mode feature in flutter.

I want to change the app's theme as dark theme or light theme when i am changing the mobile system's dark/light mode from system settings.

But, I'm not able to change the app's dark or light mode based on Mobile System's light or dark mode.

I'm using the following code.

`main.dart`

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutterrookieapp/provider/ThemeProvider.dart';
    import 'package:flutterrookieapp/utils/AppTheme.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => ThemeProvider(
                  MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
                      ? darkTheme
                      : lightTheme),
            )
          ],
          child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
            builder: (temp, theme, _) {
              return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                title: 'Flutter Sample',
                theme: MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context) == Brightness.dark
                    ? darkTheme
                    : lightTheme,
                home: HomePage(),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

`ThemeProvider.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;

  ThemeProvider(this._themeData);

  ThemeData getTheme() => _themeData;

  setTheme(ThemeData themeData) async {
    this._themeData = themeData;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use in the `MaterialApp` the `darkTheme` or `theme`
it's always from the mobile system setting

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Flutter Sample',
  darkTheme: darkTheme,
  theme: lightTheme,
  home: HomePage(),
),
```